# Can I use Apache Struts 2 with Java 11/17?

Tags: java, spring, struts, java-17

I'm currently trying to do a migration of a project from Java 8 to Java 17 and Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.1.
I've encountered dependencies on `javax.servlet` package in latest Apache Struts 2 Core (6.2.0).
I wonder if I can somehow make the project work on JVM 17?

I tried compiling the project, but with no success - the compiler says `cannot access javax.servlet.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cannot access javax.servlet.*` error is NOT caused by using Java 11 / 17.

It is happening because when you switched to Spring Boot 3.1 you have (implicitly) switched from the Java EE specs to Jakarta EE 9.  The  `javax.servlet.*` packages have been renamed to `jakarta.servlet.*`
(There are various tools and guides to help you migrate plain servlet code from Java EE to Jakarta EE, but I don't think this will help you.)

Struts 2 is also affected (afflicted) by the Java EE -> Jakarta EE issue.  Unfortunately Struts 6.x does NOT support Jakarta EE 9.  According to Struts issue  [WW-5141](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5141), the Struts team is targeting support for Jakarta EE 9 in the 7.0.0 milestone.

---

In summary:

- If you roll back to SpringBoot 2.7, you can use Java 17 and Struts 2 version 6.2.0.
- If you want to use SpringBoot 3.x, you will need to wait until Struts 2 version 7.0.0 is released.  (And don't ask me when that will be ...)